Загрузка файлов на сервер посредством fetch
function FormAdd(obj, el = new FormData()) {
    for (let key in obj)
        el.append(key, obj[key]);
    return el;
};

x.i.onchange = e => {
    (x.xml = new XMLHttpRequest()).responseType = 'json';
    x.xml.upload.onprogress = e => {}
    x.xml.onload = _ => {};
    x.xml.open("POST", document.URL, true);
    x.xml.send(FormAdd({file:x.i.files[0]}));
}

После того как файл был выбран, отправляю форму на сервер.
Хотел бы избавиться от функции FormAdd.
Возможно ли в моем случае, не добавляя лишних строчек, не усложняя
x.xml.send(FormAdd({file:x.i.files[0]}));

Лишь немного изменить?
Каков код будет если воспользоваться fetch?

Вот пример отправки файла, используя fetch https://snipp.ru/js/fetch#link-otpravka-faylov

В заголовке вопрос про fetch, в тексте вопроса про заполнение FormData - в чем в итоге заключается вопрос?

@Grundy В том, чтобы избавиться от FormData при отправке запроса, не?

@CrazyElf, если сервер ожидает FormData - ты от него никак не избавишься

@Grundy "в чем в итоге заключается вопрос?" --- написано же "Каков код будет если воспользоваться fetch?". Т.е. переписать старый XMLHttpRequest на новый fetch

@АлексейШиманский, а еще написано что вообще нужно убрать FormAdd, а про fetch - это так, вскользь
